# Docker task fails when Headless Chrome finishes executing Karma unit tests

Tags: angular, google-chrome, docker, karma-runner, puppeteer

My setup is as follows:
Angular 7, Docker, Karma, Jasmine, Headless Chrome from Puppeteer. I have 2 test suites, each with about a 100 of them, ran in parallel. Locally everything works fine, however when ran within Docker the whole build process fails the moment first suite of tests is complete.

14-Jan-2019 11:46:02    [INFO] HeadlessChrome 72.0.3617 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 12 SUCCESS (2.03 secs / 1.828 secs)

is the last line of available logs I see, sometimes it even gets cut by a few letters, depending on the build.

```
const config = {
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['parallel', 'jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
browserNoActivityTimeout: 50000,
browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
plugins: [
    require('karma-parallel'),
    require('karma-jasmine'),
    require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
    require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
    require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
browsers: ['customChromeHeadless'],
port: 9241,
singleRun: true,
autoWatch: false,
parallelOptions: {
    executors: 2,
    shardStrategy: 'round-robin'
},
reporters: ['kjhtml'],
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    dir: join(__dirname, '../../coverage'),
    reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
    fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
},
customLaunchers: {
    customChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
        ]
    }
},
proxies: {}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, dumb-init package was the solution and running the whole build through it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it?